Rewrite the objective function
Consider the objective function for Ridge Regression: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \sum_{j=1}^{p} \beta_j x_{ij})^2 + \lambda \sum_{j=1}^{p} \beta_j^2$$ Show that the objective function can be rewritten in the following form: $$\sum_{l=1}^{m} \left(\tilde{y}_l - \sum_{j=1}^{p} \beta_j \tilde{x}_{lj}\right)^2$$ by finding $m$, $\tilde{y}_l$, and $\tilde{x}_{lj}$.
The simple solution is obvious.

Determine $m$:
$$ m = n + p $$

Define $\tilde{y}$:

For the original $ n $ observations:
$$
 \tilde{y} = y_l \quad \text{for } l = 1, \ldots, n.
 $$
For the additional $ p $ observations:
$$
 \tilde{y} = 0 \quad \text{for } l = n + 1, \ldots, n + p.
 $$


Define $\tilde{x}_{ij}$:

For the original observations:
$$
 \tilde{x}_{ij} = x_l \quad \text{for } l = 1, \ldots, n.
 $$
For the additional observations:
$$
 \tilde{x}_{ij} = \begin{cases}
 \sqrt{\lambda} & \text{if } l = n + j, \\
 0 & \text{otherwise,}
 \end{cases} \quad \text{for } j = 1, \ldots, p.
 $$



However, simply combining the two parts doesn't seem meaningful. I'm curious if there are alternative approaches to address this question.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
